# In the HTTP CORS spec, what's the difference between Allow-Headers and Expose-Headers?

Tags: http, cors

In the HTTP CORS spec, what's the difference between [5.6 Access-Control-Allow-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header) and [5.3 Access-Control-Expose-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header)?

> [Allow-Headers] header indicates, as part of the response to a
>   preflight request, which header field names can be used during the
>   actual request

**UPDATE**: I was hoping someone would tell me one of these headers is sent for every request (pre-flight)... However, there is *yet* another header that is used for that: [5.9 Access-Control-Request-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-request-headers-request-header)

> [Request-Headers] header indicates which headers will be used in the actual request as part of the preflight request

BTW, I love how they (W3C) carefully worded 5.9 so that the *request header* can have a field called `_Something_ Request Header`.

I'm completely lost in the spec, is there a diagram where I can understand this process better?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers**

Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the actual request.

**Access-Control-Expose-Headers**

This header lets a server whitelist headers that browsers are allowed to access. For example:

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: So, basically these are badly named. The former is the request headers and the latter are the response headers made visible to scripts, right?

Comment: The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) states: _"The Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header is used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers will be available via Access-Control-Expose-Headers when making the actual request."_  Is this incorrect?

Comment: What will happen if the request has a header that is not included in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. For example, the server sends back "A, B, C", but the real request headers are "A, B, C, D". Will the browser refuse to send the real request?

Answer (score 18):

Just to clarify a comment above that these are badly named, these are not badly named.

They serve distinct functions.

- `Access-control-allow-headers` specifies which headers are allowed to change the state of the server.
- While `Access-control-expose-headers` has a get method getResponseHeader() method that returns the value of a particular response header. During a CORS request, the getResponseHeader() method can only access simple response headers. To be able to access other headers, you need to specify it in here.

Comment: They serve distinct functions, yet their names are so similar.  They are definitely badly named.

Comment: most people can agree the names are poor - but getting those to agree on good names ?  That's the hard part :P