# Blazor WASM Client App: Unable to read Location Response Header from HTTP Client

Tags: c#, blazor, httpclient, webassembly, response-headers

### The Issue

I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to access the 'Location' response header (or really, any response header other than 'Content-Length') from the response of an HTTP POST, using an HTTP Client inside of a Blazor Web App.

I've confirmed that the API we are calling is indeed returning the Location header; Captured via the developer tools within Chrome:
[image]

### The Code in my Blazor Client Application

We don't do anything out of the ordinary when we create the Typed/HTTP Client and register it with DI; we're just setting up the timeout on the client and Polly Retries. The handlers we're registering are for Authentication and logging respectively.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInternalApiClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    _ = services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    services.AddOptions<InternalApiClientOptions>().Configure<IConfiguration>((options, configuration) => configuration.GetSection(nameof(InternalApiClientOptions)).Bind(options));
    services
        .AddHttpClient<InternalApiClient>((serviceProvider, client) =>
        {
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<InternalApiClientOptions>>().Value;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.BaseAddress, UriKind.Absolute);
            client.Timeout = config.Timeout;
        })
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<ApiAuthorizationMessageHandler>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<ApiMetricsHandler>()
        .AddPolicyHandler((serviceProvider, _) =>
        {
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<InternalApiClientOptions>>().Value;
            return HttpPolicyExtensions
                .HandleTransientHttpError()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(config.Retries, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(config.Backoff, retryAttempt)));
        });

    return services;
}
```

```
public class ApiAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public ApiAuthorizationMessageHandler(
        IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager,
        string[] authorizedUrlArray,
        string scope)
       : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: authorizedUrlArray,
            scopes: new[] { scope });
    }
}
```

```
public class ApiMetricsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly SessionManager _sessionManager;
    private readonly AppVersionInfo _appVersionInfo;
    private readonly IMetricsMonitor _metricsMonitor;

    public ApiMetricsHandler(SessionManager sessionManager, AppVersionInfo appVersionInfo, IMetricsMonitor metricsMonitor)
    {
        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
        _appVersionInfo = appVersionInfo;
        _metricsMonitor = metricsMonitor;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> transactionDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "SessionId", _sessionManager.SessionId },
                // Etc.
            };

        _metricsMonitor.TrackEvent(_sessionManager.CurrentTransactionId, transactionDetails);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

As for the Typed Client itself, its a standard NSwag-generated client. Below is a HEAVILY edited version for brevity.

```
public partial class InternalApiClient
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private Lazy<JsonSerializerSettings> _settings;

    public InternalApiClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient; 
        _settings = new Lazy<JsonSerializerSettings>(() => 
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(settings);
            return settings;
        });
    }
    
    protected JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings { get { return _settings.Value; } }

    // FWIW, these aren't defined elsewhere.
    partial void UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(JsonSerializerSettings settings);
    partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, string url);
    partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, StringBuilder urlBuilder);
    partial void ProcessResponse(HttpClient client, HttpResponseMessage response);

    public async Task<SwaggerResponse> PostAsync(Request body, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var urlBuilder_ = new StringBuilder();
        urlBuilder_.Append("endpoint/path");
    
        var client_ = _httpClient;
        try
        {
            using (var request_ = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                var content_ = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, _settings.Value));
                content_.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                request_.Content = content_;
                request_.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
    
                PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);
    
                var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                try
                {
                    var headers_ = Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                    if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                            headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                    }
    
                    ProcessResponse(client_, response_);
    
                    var status_ = ((int)response_.StatusCode).ToString();
                    if (status_ == "400") 
                    {
                        var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<ProblemDetails>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        throw new ApiException<ProblemDetails>("bad request", (int)response_.StatusCode, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, objectResponse_.Object, null);
                    }
                    else
                    if (status_ == "202") 
                    {
                        return new SwaggerResponse((int)response_.StatusCode, headers_);
                    }
                    // Etc
                    else
                    if (status_ != "200" && status_ != "204")
                    {
                        var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
                        throw new ApiException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + (int)response_.StatusCode + ").", (int)response_.StatusCode, responseData_, headers_, null);
                    }
    
                    return new SwaggerResponse((int)response_.StatusCode, headers_); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (response_ != null)
                        response_.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### Does this work elsewhere?

I ran a test using a different project that uses the same generated API Client Class, in particular an Azure Functions project. When running in that project, I was able to receive all 8 response headers in the image above.

The DI setup logic is slightly different, but the HTTP Client setup poritions remain the same:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInternalApiClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    _ = services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

    services.AddOptions<InternalApiClientOptions>().Configure<IConfiguration>((options, configuration) => configuration.GetSection(nameof(InternalApiClientOptions)).Bind(options));

    services
        .AddHttpClient<InternalApiClient>((serviceProvider, client) =>
        {
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<InternalApiClientOptions>>().Value;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.BaseAddress, UriKind.Absolute);
            client.Timeout = config.Timeout;
        })
        .AddAzureIdentityCredentials(scopeFactory: (sp, _) =>
        {
            var config = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<InternalApiClientOptions>>().Value;
            return $"{config.Scope}/.default";
        })
        .AddPolicyHandler((serviceProvider, _) =>
        {
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<InternalApiClientOptions>>().Value;

            return HttpPolicyExtensions
                    .HandleTransientHttpError()
                    .WaitAndRetryAsync(config.Retries, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(config.Backoff, retryAttempt)));
        });

    return services;
}
```

### Final Thoughts

Because I'm able to access the response headers when using the same API Client in a different project, it feels like the issue is either Blazor as a whole, or my usage of the API client through it (via the Message Handlers). I've seen other questions/bugs regarding the Blazor and headers:

- [How to Access Httpclient headers in Blazor WASM Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401076/how-to-access-httpclient-headers-in-blazor-wasm-client)
- [HttpClient headers are empty in blazor wasm](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42179)
- [Blazor WASM C# .NET 6 Content-Disposition is not Accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70348516/blazor-wasm-c-sharp-net-6-content-disposition-is-not-accessible)

The responses for these all seem to be: Update the CORS policies on the Server. I'm not sure if this IS a CORS issue though, as a different project can receive all of the headers just fine (and the 'Content-Length' header is always received no matter what). The Server itself is used by other Apps than the two I mentioned, so I'm hesitant to start adding the 'AddCors/UseCors' calls that the linked issues mentioned.

Any insight, references would be greatly appreciated.