# Missing the custom Header in Blazor HttpClient Response

Tags: c#, .net, pagination, blazor, httpclient

I have a Blazor application that makes an HTTP GET request to my API using HttpClient to retrieve a collection of items. The API returns a JSON response, including the "X-Pagination" header, which contains pagination metadata. I can see the "X-Pagination" header when testing the API using Swagger or Postman, but it's not present when I make the same request from my Blazor application using HttpClient.

I have already verified that the "X-Pagination" header is present in the response when I inspect it using the browser's DevTools. Additionally, I checked the CORS configuration on the API, and it allows any origin, header, and method.

Here's the relevant code from my Blazor application:

```
var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
_httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("myapiuri");
_httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Constants.Json));

var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/items");

Console.WriteLine("--- Response Headers ---");
foreach (var header in response.Headers)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{header.Key}: {string.Join(", ", header.Value)}");
}
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
```

When I inspect the response variable using breakpoints or response.Headers property, I can't find the "X-Pagination" header. It seems like the header is not being returned to the Blazor application, even though it is visible in the DevTools.

These are headers from DevTools:

```
Cache-Control:
public,max-age=60,must-revalidate
Content-Length:
744876
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:
Mon, 31 Jul 2023 11:02:23 GMT
Etag:
"5019D3365DB463669B08D0C2EDD8E6F2"
Expires:
Mon, 31 Jul 2023 10:00:52 GMT
Last-Modified:
Mon, 31 Jul 2023 10:59:47 GMT
Server:
Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary:
Accept, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
X-Pagination:
{"totalCount":16,"pageSize":10,"currentPage":1,"totalPages":2}
X-Powered-By:
ASP.NET
```

and this is written by a code pasted above:

```
--- Response Headers ---
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=60
--------------------------------------
```

When I'm trying to get the value of X-Pagination Header like that:

```
string xpagination= response.Headers.GetValues("X-Pagination").FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The given header was not found.
System.InvalidOperationException: The given header was not found.
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688206

Comment: RBee, thank you so much! I literally searched all over the internet but I didn't come across this post. It works now. Oh, you've saved my day!

Comment: Side note: do not use `new HttpClient()`, leave that to the DI.

Comment: I would further add that you should use the IHttpClientFactory instead of using HttpClient directly.

Comment: Yes, I know. It is just to simplify the code to show the problem. But thank you for suggestions!