# Django Cors Allow Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: json, django, cors, getjson, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to make a simple API using Django. I have setup a django server, and then on my own html file I send requests using `$.getJSON`. So far it's been working using the [django cors headers package](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/).

Now I've been trying to send a request header to my django server, but I'm getting this error in the Chrome console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?q=example+query' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Example-Header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I'm not sure what's the problem, I have django-cors setup correctly and I am able to make requests, I'm just not allowed to set request headers.

**Setup:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:63342"
]
```

```
<script>
   $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(request) {
         request.setRequestHeader("Example-Header", 'Example-Value');
      },
   });
   $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?q=example+query", function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
</script>
```

```
@cache_page(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
def ExampleAPI(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       print(request.headers['Example-Header']) # Print Header Value 
       print(request.GET.get('q')) # Print URL Query Parameter Value   
       return JsonResponse([{"Example-Response": "Example-Response-Value"}], safe=False)
```

So what am I doing wrong? Does django-cors not support this? I tried looking it up but I could not find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From documentation for `django-cors-headers` on PyPI it looks like you need to set the `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` like so:

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    ...
    "Example-Header",
    ...
]
```

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

If you want to dive deeper into CORS here is a thorough documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Setting this in Django 3 (probably any version of Django) does not cause a response header of "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" to be returned.

Comment: The question was for the Django app to accept the header not respond with one. For that case indeed the CORS_ALLOW_HEADER wont work. See the response by Sqyed Mostafa

Comment: Thank you very much, I was missing this setting on my `settings.py` file. I just had to add all the headers that I was sending on the front-end.

Answer (score 4):

For me **CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS** didn't work.

after try couple of things I found out **CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS** would work.

```
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
    "my-custom-header",
]
```

this means now I can set 'my-custom-header' (with its value) in response header.

Comment: Good to know, though the question was for the Django app to accept a header not respond with one.

Comment: that's not a 'good thing to know', CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS didn't work for me, 
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS did.

Comment: You are talking about two connected, but slightly different, concepts in CORS. Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107459/in-the-http-cors-spec-whats-the-difference-between-allow-headers-and-expose-he

Comment: yea, you're right

-Access-control-expose-headers: cause the client to be able to access some headers specified in this (from the response header)

-Access-control-allow-headers: specifies which headers are allowed to change the state of the server.