# Fetch not receiving headers JS from Flask send_file()

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask, fetch-api

I'm writing a full stack app. I have a python backend using flask that sends a file and a Vue client that receives. Its been working fine up until the point when I try to send the filename over using a `Content-Disposition` header.

On the backend I've tried:

```py
return send_file(base_path + filename, as_attachment=True, download_name=filename)
```

And to set the headers manually,

```py
response = make_response(send_file(base_path + filename))
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f"attachment; filename=\"{filename}\""

return response
```

I've also tried to put in headers that would not be blocked by CORS just to see if the request would receive the header but to no avail,

```py
response = make_response(send_file(base_path + filename))
response.headers['Content-Type'] = "sample/info"

return response
```

I'm printing the header to the console by doing

```js
fetch('http://localhost:4999/rdownload/' + this.$route.params.id, {
method: 'GET'
}).then(res =\> {
if (res.status == '500') { }

                console.log(res.headers)
                //const header = res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
                //console.log(header)
    
                res.blob().then((blob) => {
                    /* ... */
                })
            })
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Research

In the interest of logging the solution I found and helping out anyone in the future who may be interested in knowing the answer here's what I discovered:

1. > There is a restriction to access response headers when you are using Fetch API over CORS.

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816592/20342081

   So, no matter what using the JS fetch-api you will be unable to access all headers (outside of `Cache-Control`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, and `Pragma`) unless you expose them by specifying them in a request header. That would look something like this:

   ```js
   fetch('https://myrequest/requestend/', {
       headers: {
           'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'
       }
   })
   ```
2. When a cross-origin source accesses your API you will have to expose the header from the back end as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291644/20342081

I was also confused about how the differences between `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. In my case the solution was use "expose headers" on both the frontend and the backend (and allow wouldn't work). However, Allow has its own applications which I have yet to understand fully. For those endeavoring check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28108431/20342081

## Solution

I implemented these things in my code by doing:

```py
class RequestResult(Resource):
    def get(self, index):
        base_path = f"Requests/{index}/"
        filename = os.listdir(base_path)[0]

        response = make_response(send_file(base_path + filename, as_attachment=True, download_name=filename))
        response.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = "Content-Disposition"

        return response
```

And on the front end exposing the header as well on the fetch request:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:4999/rdownload/' + this.$route.params.id, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'
    }
})
```

I hope this is helpful for the next 5 people who open this in the next 10 years!